# Swiper.js i can't see any animation in fade effect

Tags: javascript, slider, fade, swiper.js

I cant see any fade animation in my swiper. I am using swiper.js version 8.2.6
That's my piece of code
I try to set speed to default and crossFade to false, it does't work

```
import Swiper, { Navigation, EffectFade } from "swiper";
import 'swiper/css';
const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
        modules: [EffectFade, Navigation],
        spaceBetween: 30,
        speed: 500,
        effect: 'fade',
        fadeEffect: {
            crossFade: true
        },
        navigation: {
            nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
            prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
          },
      });


<div class="swiper">
     <div class="swiper-wrapper">
         <div class="swiper-slide">
              <figure class="swiper-image-wrapper">
                     <img class="swiper-image" src="/img/slider-one/slider-one-1.jpg" alt="slide" width="573" height="751">
              </figure>
              <div class="swiper-text-wrapper-right">
                     <h5 class="font-18">Prasa</h5>
                     <p class="font-16">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo.</p>
              </div>
               </div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">
                        <figure class="swiper-image-wrapper">
                            <img class="swiper-image" src="/img/slider-one/slider-one-1.jpg" alt="slide" width="573" height="751">
                        </figure>
                        <div class="swiper-text-wrapper-right">
                            <h5 class="font-18">Kino</h5>
                            <p class="font-16">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo.</p>
                 </div>
             </div>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-nav col-lg-6 offset-lg-6">
                    <div class="swiper-nav-button swiper-button-prev"><img src="/img/icons/arrow-slider.svg" alt="arrow previous" width="25" height="14"></div>
                    <div class="swiper-nav-button swiper-button-next"><img src="/img/icons/arrow-slider.svg" alt="arrow next" width="25" height="14"></div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Resolved by adding importing css in JS file `import 'swiper/css/effect-fade';`